# NotifyIcon - prevent multiple database query

Tags: c#, notifyicon

I have a `NotifyIcon` and I set balloon text with `MouseMove event`. The balloon text comes from a database. This results continuous database query.

```
private void notifyIcon1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //database operations.......
}
```

How can I prevent this? I want to set balloon text once when mouse on NotifyIcon.

Comment: Which is not an event for NotifyIcon, so nope

Comment: @KevinSijbers, oops, you are right :)

Comment: I'm guessing that logic got kovak to use MouseMove in the first place, BalloonTipShown is a stretch when you are looking for a mouse event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach would be to add a Timer to your Form and set its Interval to a delay like 1 second.  This delay would be how often the user could hit the database.  Setup a Flag that gets reset by the Timer and check it in your NotifyIcon event.  Something like:

```
    private bool AllowUpdate = true;

    private void notifyIcon1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (AllowUpdate)
        {
            AllowUpdate = false; // don't allow updates until after delay

            // ... hit the database ...
            // ... update your text ...

            timer1.Start(); // don't allow updates until after delay
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // reset so it can be updated again
        AllowUpdate = true;
        timer1.Stop();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the BalloonTipShown event (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.balloontipshown(v=vs.110).aspx) 
The behaviour you are looking for matched that event alot better then the MouseMove event

Comment: Also it's good to cache the results and not go to the database for the same record again and again on every tooltip.

Comment: @Kevin Sijbers It does not seem to work, nothing happen.

Comment: Are you using System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon, not some other class? How is the event assigned to the object? This should load database information once when displaying the tooltip

Comment: @Kevin Sijbers Yes, i am using the standard NotifyIcon.

`private void notifyIcon1_BalloonTipShown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            notifyIcon1.Text = "bbbbbb";
        }`

NotifyIcon text remains unchanged.